# Is there way to reuse WebService ? Spring in Java

Tags: java, spring, web-services, web.xml

I have one WebService class, which I would like to use more times with different facades/services implementing one interface. I tried to create two beans from one class and map them onto two different addresses as two web services, however  on the both addresses there are all requests targeted to second instance of WebService. It is important to implement all these web services by one client just by changing url of WSDL. That mean all attributes should be same (targetNamespace, name, portName, serviceName) otherwise an Exception is thrown on client.

Class looks like this:

```
@WebService
public class ServiceX {
    private IFacade facade;

    public ServiceX(IFacade facade) {
         this.facade = facade;
    }
    @WebMethod
    public Result getResult(){
        return facade.getResult();
    }
}
```

Then I am using Spring with XML configuration like this:

```
<wss:binding url="/serviceonews">
    <wss:service>
        <ref bean="serviceone" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<ws:service id="serviceone">
    <ws:bean>
        <bean class="ServiceX">
            <constructor-arg ref="firstFacade" />
        </bean>
    </ws:bean>
</ws:service>

<wss:binding url="/servicetwows">
    <wss:service>
        <ref bean="servicetwo" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<ws:service id="servicetwo">
    <ws:bean>
        <bean class="ServiceX">
            <constructor-arg ref="secondFacade" />
        </bean>
    </ws:bean>
</ws:service>

<bean id="firstFacade" class="FirstFacade" />
<bean id="secondFacade" class="SecondFacade" />
```

Here is web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WSSpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSSpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/serviceonews</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/servicetwows</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution finally. Everytime I tried to create 2 beans from one class the newest bean replaced the already existed.
The solution of having two same WSDLs is not in creating two beans from one class, but in settings of attributes in annotation. I my case I needed two web services inheriting from base logic with different constructor, which was filling base logic with concrete facade/service.

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://package/", name="ServiceX", portName="ServiceXPort", serviceName="ServiceName")
public class ServiceX extends ServiceXBase {

    public ServiceX(IFacade facade) {
         super(facade);
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Result getResult(){
        return super.getResult();
    }
}
```